# How to Reset a Form Automatically when Navigating Back in Flutter

Tags: flutter, forms

i have a screen has to textformfield 1- customAmountController , 2-messageController and i fill that and go to next screen but when i pop from this screen to my form screen my 2 textformfiled should be empty  so how can i do that

[image]

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I am assuming you don't want changes to persist between visits to a certain page. With code we could also determine exactly why the problem is occurring, so I will proceed to deductively propose possible problems.

**Possible Problem #1:**
Changes persisting are likely due to a `TextEditingController` being of a higher scope than your page widget. If the controller wasn't of another scope, it would reset to its initial state every time the page loads.
You can solve this by resetting the controller in the page's build method or by moving the controller inside the class.

**Possible Problem #2:**
Another likely problem is that the page isn't being reloaded when being navigated to with a pop method. If method 1 doesn't work, then try navigating away from this page with the following:
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/myRoute").then((value) => setState(() {}));`
Popping will definitely reload the page(if it is a stateful widget) after this.
If you provide code, I could tell you without having to guess the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `whenComplete()` to clear your `TextEditingControllers`, Here is an example:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourPage()),
).whenComplete(() {
  customAmountController.clear();
  messageController.clear();
});
```

In this code snippet, `whenComplete()` is used to clear the `TextEditingControllers` (`customAmountController` and `messageController`) after navigating to the `YourPage` page. This ensures that the text fields are cleared when the user returns from the `YourPage` page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because you use `Navigator.pop(context);` to back to your pages.

Remember, `Navigator.pop(context);` is not reset your previous activty. So, if you want that you `TextFormField` empty when you're back to you page, Just change your `Navigation.pop(context);` to Route Function , like

```
Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => yourPage()));
```

or

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/routeName');
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is when you go back and whenever you press on any back button or whenever you handle back button callback after that you should clear all your textEditingController clear. Below thing you can do

```
your_text_editing_controller.clear();
```